# Combine tab and listview for android

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, tabs

I'm developing an application for android that is supposed to have three tabs that shows three different listviews. It should look pretty much like this video example:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/

The problem i have is that TabActivity is deprecated and i can't found any good tutorials for the Fragment view (which I think is the one to replace TabView). Anyone know how to combine these two views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into ActionBar and Fragments. Maybe the following link could help you out? http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tab-layout-in-android-with-actionbar-and-fragment/?lang=en

Comment: ActionBar was the thing! Thanks!